# JSON.parse передает вместо содержимого объектов их тип

Tags: javascript

Данные, которые беру из localStorage - goods:   [{"article":"1179ДЖ-225","count":1,"size":""},{"article":"992ДЖ-215","count":1,"size":""}].

```
location.href = 'shopping_cart.php?id=' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('goods'))
```

Получаю: shopping_cart.php?id=[object%20Object],[object%20Object].

Как вывести объекты в нормальном виде из массива?

Comment: так а в каком формате надо? тем более у вас в goods не один итем.

Comment: Что такое "в нормальном виде" мы должны своей головой догадаться?

Comment: JSON.parse возвращает объекты, которые затем опять приводятся к строке. Если тебе нужна строка - зачем вообще использовать JSON.parse?

Comment: Что происходит с объектом в массиве, когда использую JSON.parse?

Comment: @Zahar, ничего не происходит, потому что в JSON.parse не передается массив ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ в него передается _строка_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это массив с объектами, то с помощью **JSON.parse()** ты разбираешь строку, потом обращаешься с элементу полученного массива, указав номер нужного товара (он вернет объект), а потом обращаешься через точку к параметру **article**, чтоб уже получить само значение. Вроде так должно быть:

```
var articles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('goods'));
location.href = 'shopping_cart.php?id=' + articles[номер товара].article
```

Comment: Благодарю, то, что надо

Comment: @Zahar, пожалуйста. Но советую перед тем как пользоваться функцией прочитать как она работает. На сайте developer.mozilla.org хорошая документация по всему JavaScript.